# Необычный синтаксис fasm

Tags: ассемблер, fasm, nasm

Решил немного разгрузить мозги чем-то другим, отличным от рабочих вопросов. И вот мой выбор пал на тему "ассемблер" :) В свое время плотно прогал на `Turbo Pascal 5.5` + `TASM`, но это было ооочень давно. В основном это касалось работы с видеоадаптером `CGA`. А когда появились `EGA/VGA` - актуальность начала падать. Ну это так, предисловие что-ли. Сейчас решил немного окунуться "в современность". Ассемблеров тьма, мне приглянулся `fasm`. Написал простенькую прогу для теста:

```
format PE64 console

include "C:/Tools/Fasm/INCLUDE/win64ax.inc"

.data

Message         db 'Hello World!',0
Message.length  = $ - Message
HandleFile      dq ?

.code

proc PrintFunc
  stdcall [WriteConsole], [HandleFile], Message, Message.length, 0, 0
  ret
endp

start:

  sub rsp, 40  ; резервирование в стеке (4 * 8) + 8
  and spl, -16 ; и выравнивание на 16

  stdcall [GetStdHandle], STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE
  mov [HandleFile],rax
  stdcall PrintFunc, HandleFile
  stdcall [ExitProcess],0

.end start
```

Где-то по докам, где-то по примерам из сети. Но обратил внимание на странное оформление секций, процедур. Вот и возник ряд вопросов:

1. Это фишки собственных макросов `fasm`'а?
2. А как такое же написать, к примеру, для `nasm`?
3. А такое же, написанное для п.2 потом сам `fasm` компильнет?
4. Какова ценность вот такого "синтаксиса" (вдруг потом понадобится `gas`'ом компилировать)?

Comment: Если собираетесь писать на ассемблере, то можно забыть про совместимость синтаксиса макросов между разными ассемблерами. Если masm и tasm была условная совместимость, то между masm, fasm, nasm, gas - практически никакой совместимости нет.

Comment: А если не использовать макросы вообще? Я по поводу fasm, nasm, gas.

Comment: Все равно не получится. У gas совершенно другой синтаксис ([AT&T](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/AT%26T-синтаксис)). fasm и nasm ближе к друг другу, чем к masm, например, но даже для в минимальной программе без макросов будут отличия в синтаксисе.

Comment: У gas же есть ключик для использования intel-синтаксиса вроде. Ну а так - понятно.